# Mern heroku I got internal server error when I reload the page

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

When I reload my Heroku page, I got an internal server error as a status code 500.
But it doesn't happen in my local environment.
On top of this,
 when I access route address which redirects correctly and displays normally.
When I reload the page, in network information of chrom dev tool said the page didn't process any process. 
[image]
What is the issue with my program? 
this is the website.
https://boiling-falls-61617.herokuapp.com/

This is my error and code.
error

```
2020-03-15T19:33:53.875586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/dashboards/5e6b999eb7f157252c8c6937" host=boiling-falls-61617.herokuapp.com request_id=785b2a93-2739-455f-856e-e59fb5af18ce fwd="99.251.226.61" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
```

server code

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    // don't serve api routes to react app
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
  });
  console.log("Serving React App...");
}
```

frontend

```
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <PrivateRoute path='/dashboards/:dashboardId' component={DashBoard} />
        <Route exact path='/' component={SignIn} />
        <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
        <PrivateRoute
          path='/(dashboards|calendar)/:dashboardId/columns/:columnId/tasks/:taskId'
          render={props => <CardModal {...props} />}
        />
        <Route path='/calendar/:dashboardId' component={Calendar} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue; Worked on local, not on Heroku.
For me the fix was:

- I had to explicitly add `const path = require("path");` to my server.js file.

After adding this, it seemed to work for me.

You may also check the heroku logs for more detail on the server error, by going to your heroku account and click the app then click the  button in the navigation bar and select "View logs"

Comment: I'm guessing you looked at brad traversy's course?

Comment: No, I haven't.  I'll have to check him out.